# Resume uploading with built-in Windows FTP client

Tags: windows, ftp

Is it possible to resume uploading with built-in Windows FTP client after FTP client failure/disconnection from previous point?

For example, how to achieve following scenario: build-in FTP client uploads 40% of file, connection was lost, client reconnects and starts uploading of the rest 60% of file? Other FTP clients capable to do this but I restricted by using only software available just after Windows installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Windows command-line `ftp.exe` does not support transfer resuming.

---

But you can just automatically download any small 3rd party portable command-line FTP client that supports automatic resume and use that.

For example the following PowerShell code downloads [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) package, extracts it and starts a resumable upload:

```sh
$winscpAssembly = "WinSCPnet.dll"
if (Test-Path $winscpAssembly)
{
    Write-Host "WinSCP already downloaded"
}
else
{
    $bestReleaseUrl = "https://sourceforge.net/projects/winscp/best_release.json"
    $winscpBestRelease = Invoke-WebRequest $bestReleaseUrl | ConvertFrom-Json
    $url = $winscpBestRelease.release.url
    $url = $url -replace "-Setup.exe", "-Automation.zip"

    Write-Host "Downloading ..."
    $winscpArchive = "WinSCP-Automation.zip"
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $webclient.DownloadFile($url, $winscpArchive)
    Write-Host "Done"

    Write-Host "Extracting $winscpArchive ..."
    Expand-Archive $winscpArchive .

    Write-Host "Done"
}

Add-Type -Path $winscpAssembly

$ftp_host = "ftp.example.com"
$ftp_path = "/target/path/"
$upload_path = "C:\big\file.dat"
Write-Host "Starting resumable upload of $upload_path to $ftp_host ..."
# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = $ftp_host
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

$session.PutFiles($upload_path, $ftp_path).Check()
```

To run the PowerShell script (`upload.ps1`) use:

```
powershell.exe -File upload.ps1 -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

*The script uses PowerShell 5 `Expand-Archive` cmdlet. If you need to use older version of PowerShell, check an old revision of this answer for a solution with use of `Shell.Application` object.*

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

Another option is to implement the resume manually using [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest).

See [How to continue or resume FTP upload after interruption of internet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41779788/850848).

Again you can use the `FtpWebRequest` from a PowerShell script. See [Upload files with FTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867385/850848).